# Configurar Ldap en pentaho cde 8.3

Tags: ldap, pentaho, openldap

Hola estoy intentando configurar pentaho 8.3 para que se conecte a un servidor openldap. Cuando termino de configurarlo que levanto el servidor de pentaho no me da ningun error y cuando intento iniciar sesion me da el siguiente error "A login error occurred.
Please try again." y lo configuré como dice la documentcion https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/8.3/Setup/LDAP_security
Esta es la configuracion del archivo applicationContext-security-ldap.properties

```
contextSource.providerUrl=ldap://10.12.25.253:389/dc=gases,dc=cu
contextSource.userDn=cn=admin2,ou=Usuarios,dc=gases,dc=cu
contextSource.password=123

userSearch.searchBase=cn=Gases,ou=Grupos
userSearch.searchFilter=(sAMAccountName\={0})

populator.convertToUpperCase=false
populator.groupRoleAttribute=cn
populator.groupSearchBase=ou=Pentaho
populator.groupSearchFilter=(roleOccupant:={0})
populator.rolePrefix=
populator.searchSubtree=true

allAuthoritiesSearch.roleAttribute=cn
allAuthoritiesSearch.searchBase=ou=Pentaho
allAuthoritiesSearch.searchFilter=(objectClass=group)

allUsernamesSearch.usernameAttribute=cn
allUsernamesSearch.searchBase=ou=Usuarios
allUsernamesSearch.searchFilter=objectClass=person

adminRole=cn=administrador,ou=Pentaho,dc=gases,dc=cu
adminUser=cn=admin2,ou=Usuarios,dc=gases,dc=cu
providerType=ldapCustomConfiguration
```

[image: Esta es una imagen de la estructura de mi ldap]

Esta es una imagen de la estructura de mi ldap

Comment: Hola! No hay nada más en los logs? Alguna forma de configurar los logs para que sean más detallados?

Comment: No no me sale mas nada en los logs